# Custom short URLs in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, joomla1.5, short-url, custom-url

I had a long ugly long URLs for Joomla articles. Being advised here to enable SEF, I got:

```
www.domain.com/cat1/subcat1/120-results-of-DES-project-in-2011
```

Nicer, but I also want custom short URL for specified article, like:

```
www.domain.com/des
```

Is this possible in Joomla 1.5? Simply adding rule to `.htaccess` is possible but not what I'd like, because:

1. I'd prefer that the short URL remains in the Location bar after the page is loaded
2. Joomla to use that short URL whenever the articles is clicked from news etc.

(P.S.: if it's not possible, then I'd be happy with some simple URL "aliaser" for Joomla, which would work similarly to `.htaccess`, but preferably with short URL remaining in the browsers' location bar.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Trev mentioned you need to turn on SEF URLs. In the admin, in the Site menu click on Global Configuration. In the Site configuration you should see a box for SEO settings. Turn on all 3 options unless you don't want the .html suffix, that one can be left off.

Now Joomla will create URLs like this -

www.yourdomain.com/parent-menu-alias/child-menu-alias/article-alias.html

If the menu item is linking directly to an article, then it would be -

www.yourdomain.com/menu-alias.html

Comment: Thanks Brent, but what if I want to make a short alias URL `domain.com/alias` for article `domain.com/cat1/subcat1/120-name-of-the-article`?

Comment: It will depend on how many URLs you want. If you want many, then you should invest in sh404sef extension (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) to make custom URLs. Otherwise you can make specific menu items in a hidden menu to create the URLs or use htaccess. This is not a built in behavior.

Comment: Great Brent, thanks! In the meantime, I used htaccess for the job, but the extension looks good!

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled SEF and htaccess in the Global Configuration? If you do then the URLs to any articles is controlled by the article's alias. e.g. if you want an article to be

http://mysite.com/my-url just open the article in the article manager and change the Alias field to my-url

Comment: this is not working, the SEF article URL is more complicated, as Brent wrote. I need just simple alias to it.

Comment: yes, for more complicated urls you should use sh404sef, joomsef or some other 3rd party component. Those 2 are particularly good.